# bash: cookiecutter: command not found (cookiecutter installed using conda)

Tags: python-3.x, conda, git-bash, cookiecutter

I have installed python cookiecutter using conda:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install coockiecutter
```

In anaconda prompt "`cookiecutter --version`" shows "1.6.0 from `d:\users\username\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`.

Upon running `cookiecutter` command in `git bash` and it gives an error "`bash: cookiecutter: command not found`".

I have already added the path where `cookiecutter` is installed in windows environment variable "path".
Could you please suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cookiecutter command not found after installing with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172539/cookiecutter-command-not-found-after-installing-with-pip)

Answer (score 0):

> I have already added the path where cookiecutter is installed in windows environment variable "path"

Then make sure to open a *new* CMD session that will inherit your PATH.

Before typing "bash", check the command is accessible with:

```
where cookiecutter
```

Then type "`bash`" and go on with your installation process.

As the [OP pratik shirbhate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9744298/pratik-shirbhate) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54799957/bash-cookiecutter-command-not-found-cookiecutter-installed-using-conda/54800145?noredirect=1#comment96392045_54800145):

> there was a correction in the directory path and I could capture that with `where` command

Comment: Thank you Von, there was a correction in the directory path and I could capture that with `where` command

Comment: @pratikshirbhate Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling for cookiecutter is wrong. Please check that

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install cookiecutter
```

If you are using Mac. you can also do:

```
brew install cookiecutter
```

Using conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cookiecutter
```